# Pyspark code to select data from HIVE table and write in HDFS as parquet format

Tags: sql, python-2.7, hdfs, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to select data from a partioned HIVE table (partioned on column - label_yyyy_mm_dd) for a selected date range and write append in HDFS as a parquet file. However getting error. Below is the code and error.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions 
import current_date, date_format, date_sub from datetime import datetime, timedelta import datetime 
  q  = """select label_yyyy_mm_dd
        ,label_yyyy_mm
        ,q_media_name
        ,a_accepted
        ,a_end_ts
        ,a_media_name
        ,a_resource_name
        ,a_start_ts
        ,k_callpurpose
        ,k_srf
        ,q_entry_ordinal
        ,q_interaction_id
        ,q_interaction_type
        ,q_ixn_resource_id
        ,q_resource_name
        ,a_consult_rcv_warm_engage_time
        ,a_consult_rcv_warm_hold_time
        ,a_consult_rcv_warm_wrap_time
        ,a_customer_handle_count
        ,a_customer_talk_duration
        ,a_interaction_resource_id
        ,a_interaction_id
        ,a_wrap_time
        a_technical_result
        ,k_ixn_type
        ,k_ixn_type_source
        ,k_transfer_count
        ,k_language
        ,k_agentauth
        ,k_auth,k_rg
        ,k_channel
        ,k_gms_result
        ,k_connid
        ,k_rbcprimaryid
        ,k_agent_id
        ,a_interaction_resource_ordinal 
    from prod_T0V0_cct0.cct0_gim_measures_gold A 
    inner join prod_T0V0_cct0.yle0_gim_date_time B on A.a_start_date_time_key = B.date_time_key     where label_yyyy_mm_dd
>='2017/03/07'      AND label_yyyy_mm_dd <='2017/03/31'"""   spark.sql(q).write.mode('append').parquet('hdfs:/prod/11323/app/H9A0/data/T0V0/DIG/test.parquet/label_yyyy_mm_dd=%s' %label_yyyy_mm_dd)
```

Error message :-

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-e695e7530d80> in <module>()
     42         where label_yyyy_mm_dd >='2017/03/07'
     43         AND label_yyyy_mm_dd <='2017/03/31'"""
---> 44 spark.sql(q).write.mode('append').parquet('hdfs:/prod/11323/app/H9A0/data/T0V0/DIG/test.parquet/label_yyyy_mm_dd=%s'%label_yyyy_mm_dd)

NameError: name 'label_yyyy_mm_dd' is not defined
```

Comment: I feel label_yyyy_mm_dd is a column and is a folder too. You have q = """select label_yyyy_mm_dd and so on. You cannot pass in the column name directly. Do this, label_yyyy_mm_dd = q.select('label_yyyy_mm_dd'). Do, a collect on it and can you paste the OP?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have

```
q = """select label_yyyy_mm_dd
    ,label_yyyy_mm
    ,q_media_name and so on'''
```

Create DataFrame which has columns from 'q'.

```
df = spark.sql(q)
```

Then, select 'label_yyyy_mm_dd' column from DataFrame 'df'

```
label_yyyy_mm_dd = df.select('label_yyyy_mm_dd')
```

Convert them to string by taking the first value

```
label_yyyy_mm_dd_coll = ",".join(str("{0}".format(value.label_yyyy_mm_dd )) for 
value in label_yyyy_mm_dd.take(1))
```

Pass, the variable to write it.

```
df.write.mode('append').parquet('hdfs:/prod/11323/app/H9A0/data/T0V0/DIG/test.parquet/label_yyyy_mm_dd=%s' % label_yyyy_mm_dd_coll)
```

Comment: If i have the space between % and label_yyyy_mm_dd, iam still facing the same error message.

Comment: Try the solution.

Comment: 42         where label_yyyy_mm_dd >='2017/03/07'
43         AND label_yyyy_mm_dd <='2017/03/31'"""
---> 44 label_yyyy_mm_dd = q.select('label_yyyy_mm_dd')
45 label_yyyy_mm_dd_coll = ",".join(str("{0}".format(value.ext_yearmonth)) for value in label_yyyy_mm_dd.collect())
     46 spark.sql(q).write.mode('append').parquet('hdfs:/prod/11323/app/H9A0/data/T0V0/DIG/test.parquet/label_yyyy_mm_dd=%s' % label_yyyy_mm_dd_coll)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'select'

Comment: Oops, I was testing using my DataFrame. Changed it.

Comment: No luck :(  
     42         where label_yyyy_mm_dd >='2017/03/07'
     43         AND label_yyyy_mm_dd <='2017/03/31'"""
---> 44 label_yyyy_mm_dd = q.select('label_yyyy_mm_dd')
     45 label_yyyy_mm_dd_coll = ",".join(str("{0}".format(value.label_yyyy_mm_dd )) for value in label_yyyy_mm_dd.take(1))
     46 spark.sql(q).write.mode('append').parquet('hdfs:/prod/11323/app/H9A0/data/T0V0/DIG/test.parquet/label_yyyy_mm_dd=%s' % label_yyyy_mm_dd_coll)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'select'

Comment: Did you do this label_yyyy_mm_dd.take(1)? Can you tell me what is the data under that column?

Comment: Did you do this first? label_yyyy_mm_dd = q.select('label_yyyy_mm_dd')

Comment: I don't have anything as label_yyyy_mm_dd.take(1). I just have the column label_yyyy_mm_dd. And when i added the above code as you suggested getting error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'select' on label_yyyy_mm_dd = q.select('label_yyyy_mm_dd')

Comment: q = '''SELECT columns''' would be a string. Simply passing, %label_yyyy_mm_dd does not achieve you with the solution because it does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the complete dataframe into q dataframe. So, when you are passing

```
%label_yyyy_mm_dd
```

it was unable to read that column
try this:

```
label_yyyy_mm_dd = q.select(“label_yyyy_mm_dd”) \
                  .rdd.map(lambda x:str(x[“label_yyyy_mm_dd”])).collect()
```

(perform collect if that column contains multiple values
otherwise if you need only first value just replace .first()

but collect is not suggested as it implies load.

Comment: You said, it was unable to read that column => Firstly, 'q' is a String (not a DataFrame), when there is no such column `label_yyyy_mm_dd`, it is obvious that it will throw `NameError: name 'label_yyyy_mm_dd' is not defined`. If you do `type(q)`, you see it prints `<type'str'>`.